# Undefined symbol exception while using EAX,EBX,ECX and so on

Tags: assembly, x86

I am getting an undefined symbol exception while using registers EAX,EBX,ECX and so on
I am new to X86 programming so any help would be appreciated

```
data segment
msg db 10,13,'enter the number$'
msg1 db 10,13,'the result$'
nline db 13,10,'$'
ttho dd 10000
ten db 10
tho dw 1000
h dw 0100
product dw ?
num1 db ?
num2 db ?
data ends


code segment
assume cs:code,ds:data
start:
mov eax,data
mov ds,eax
mov eax,0001h
mov ebx,0000h
mov ecx,0000h
mov edx,0000h
```

[image]

[image]

after putting .386 i am still getting this error

Comment: Which program are you using to assemble?

Comment: Which assembler are you using? (masm,yasm,gas,nasm,tasm,fasm,... there are loads of different ones and the syntax depends on which one you use.)

Comment: TASM(Turbo assembler)

Comment: @Denson Are you sure you are using a 32-bit version? 16-bit versions won't know about eax...

Comment: the debugger is named TD32 is it safe to assume that this is a 32 bit version?
because the TASM program i am using i got it from the college itself

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you're getting? It should have a line number that will allow us to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: You have to tell it that you want to generate 32-bit code.  It takes a directive, something like `.386`

Comment: even the TLINK file is named TLINK32 with loads of other files named in a similar manner so i think its the 32 bit version only!

Comment: The answer that told you to put `%` everywhere is gone because it was completely wrong. Get rid of the `%` and add `.386`.

Comment: yes @us2012 i deleted '%' and then added .386 before the start of the data segment still i am getting those errors
infact for .386 also its showing illegal instruction

Comment: @Denson Did you put `.368` instead of `.386` by mistake?

Comment: yes now it is working 
by the way those push and pop instructions are giving errors
so i better stick to macros only then?

Comment: Please don't keep changing your code. It makes the answers look wrong, since they are pointing out errors in code that no longer matches what is on the site.

Comment: ok @RaymondChen so now i have made the code how it was!

Comment: why should you use an ancient assembler like that when there are many free assemblers today that can support even the newest x86_64 or AVX2 instruction set

Comment: you have a valid point but even this should work right?
because it identifies the .386 instruction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You need to add `.386` at the top of your file to generate 32-bit code, like Hans Passant says.
- Your `data` segment is entirely missing, together with `msg`. Add `data` and `msg`, then the undefined symbol errors for those will go away, too.
- The `push msg` before the function call and `pop msg` in the function looks weird. Depending on the definition of `msg`, this *can* work but it feels awkward.

Comment: i have added the data segment in the actual code din find it relevant to post it here

Comment: normally i use macros for printing msgs was just trying it using a procedure and do we have to just add .368 at the top nothing else?

Comment: `.386`, yeah, that will fix your undefined symbol errors about `eax` etc.